# why form submission in ie and chrome dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a success notification that is done on my website (html5/bootstrap/jquery) http://www.bassmanager.com & for some reason my users cannot see the success notification on the contact form.. but in firefox this is working, what is stopping this from working correctly on ie and chrome.

goto homepage and click contact us <-- I still get the form but no succession which leads to people submitting the form 1000 times.. thanks!

Comment: Did you bother checking the error console? *XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bassmanager.com/contact-process.php. Origin http://www.bassmanager.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin*

Answer (score 2):

If you access your site without www, it will works... =)

You're doing an ajax request to http://bassmanager.com/contact-process.php, which is different of www.bassmanager.com...

According to the [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (or just CORS), these domains are different, so your script hosted at www.bassmanager.com can't make a XMLHttpRequest request to bassmanager.com. Unless this is explicitly authorized by the target domain, by sending a CORS header in its response.

In a context where you don't have control over the target domain (isn't your case), you could also use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to make a request between different domains. But as I said, for your context this is not necessary. Just change your ajax post URL or allow the bassmanager.com origin in your server.

Comment: wth weird so .htaccess it?

Comment: @user1822748 No, fix up the value in your `#siteUrl` hidden input field (or simply don't prefix URLs with a hostname at all)

Comment: @Phil exactly... this is the easiest and best solution...